# visual studios 2010 search variable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, search, breakpoints

Im working on a new, large project that I am unfamiliar with. Im trying to trace down where a certain part of an event is triggered and I think I've nailed it down but Im not 100% sure.The event (which deals with one button on a menu) is dealt with on a very abstract level because of all the dependency injection. Because of this, my break point only shows variables in a very abstract form. Deep down inside them I believe that there are some values that correlate to my specific button (ie the label). Is there a way I can search through an object for a specific string much like you would search through a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for object data with the [OzCode](http://o.oz-code.com/features#search) extension.